# Has sscanf changed in MSVC++ 15+?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, scanf

Given the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char color[256];
    float c,m,y,k;  
    const char* arguments = "0.8500 1 0 0 (Violet)";
    memset(color, 0, 256 * sizeof(char));
    if (sscanf(arguments, "%f %f %f %f %256c", &c, &m, &y, &k, color) == 5)
        std::cout << color; 
}
```

this has been in production and working for at least 10 to 15 years (it outputs the color name):

> (Violet)

but using the latest Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, or in MSVC++ 15 too, the result has changed. **Instead of 5 the result is 4.** Using gcc or clang the result is also 5, as it was in previous versions of MSVC++. Is there something wrong in this code or does someone know why these different results between compilers?

- [MSVC++](http://rextester.com/JTZ24191)
- [GCC](http://rextester.com/MDO97339)
- [CLANG](http://rextester.com/GYR14194)

Comment: `"%256c"` expects to read *exactly* 256 characters. Why not use `"%255s"` ?

Comment: I know, this actually solves the issue, but unfortunately it was not implemented like this in many parts of our source code.

Comment: That your problem here, just fix your code and move on.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That comment is *exactly* 1 answer to this question. Why not add it below!? (It is also the correct answer, apart from maybe suggesting to change to not using `sprintf` since it is not type safe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"%256c"` expects to read *exactly* 256 characters, as specified in the C standard (7.21.6.2 §12) :

> **c** Matches a sequence of characters of exactly the number specified by the field
>   width (1 if no field width is present in the directive).

To get the bevavior you want, you can use eg. `"%255s"`, which matches *at most* 255 (non-whitespace) characters.

On the question of why this behavior is different between (versions of) implementations : it seems several implementations do not enforce the *exactly* part, while the one you used does.

Since your code relies on non-standard behavior, having the code break at some point should not be unexpected.

Comment: Library behavior, the compiler is not involved.